# Using python, I'm trying to access text from a database, but I'm getting different results when I do just print vs a foreach loop

Tags: python, database, pyodbc, filemaker

Using python, I'm trying to access text from a database (FileMaker Pro) using a pyodbc connection. When I use a foreach loop, for some reason the text prints. But, when I just straight away print it then I think it prints the location or something. The following code explains it better:

```
 import pyodbc
 connectString = "DSN=FMODBC32;UID=...;PWD=..." 
 connection = pyodbc.connect(connectString)
 cursor = connection.cursor()

 param = cursor.execute("select Parameters from Info")
       ## Parameters = fieldName in the database, Info = tableName in database

 print(param)
       ## This prints: <pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x08930C20>  (Is this the location?)

 for info in param:
     print(info) 
       ## This prints the actual text I need, not the location
```

I want to just do print(param) and not a whole foreach loop to get the text I need. Any advice?

Comment: see https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#methods

Comment: Your first print just prints the Cursor object. It doesn't appear to implement `__repr__`, so you just get the class name and its location in memory. Your for loop then iterates the Cursor (the execution results), and _those_ prints show the returned results. In short, you're printing different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(param)
```

only prints you the param object.

You should add

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select Parameters from Info")
param = cursor.fetchall()
```

and print(param) should be ok.